# Can I use Laravel Mix on a project that already uses Gulp?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, gulp

Bit of a "first steps" question this one.

I am working on a project that uses gulp, and have found a nice vue component that I would like to incorporate.

I have been recommended to use Laravel mix, but will installing mix mess up the current installation ?

Is there a good way to use vue with gulp ?  is doing this "safer" than running gulp and laravel mix ?

Comment: Why don't you test that out yourself? You can always remove it.

Comment: Agree with @Kyslik, when you encountered problems that's when you ask for help.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I wanted to avoid making any large mistakes in the installation :-).  I think the answer to Kysliks' question is "fear and lack of understanding" :-)...

Comment: If you are properly using Version control system (VCS) - like git - you should have no fear. Good Luck!